# Help with Complex CAML Query - Multiple OR Conditions

Tags: caml

I need some assistance with a complex CAML query. I can get parts of it working but cannot get all of it working together. What I need in laymans terms is this:

```
Where Country = US 

AND Status BEGINSWITH A OR Status BEGINSWITH B OR Status BEGINSWITH C 
OR Status BEGINSWITH D OR Status BEGINSWITH E OR Status BEGINSWITH F

AND Relationship NOT EQUALS to N/A OR IsComplete EQUALS Yes OR IsApproved EQUALS Yes
```

I have the statement laid out like this:

```
<Where>
<And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name='ContractingCountry' /><Value Type='Text'>Canada</Value></Eq>
        <Or>
            <Or>
              <Or>
              <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></BeginsWith>
              <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>B</Value></BeginsWith>
             </Or>
              <Or>
                  <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>C</Value></BeginsWith>
                  <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></BeginsWith>
              </Or>
            </Or>
            <Or>
                <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>E</Value></BeginsWith>
                <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>F</Value></BeginsWith>
            </Or>
        </Or>

</And>
<And>
        <Or>
              <Neq><FieldRef Name='Relationship' /><Value Type='Text'>N/A</Value></Neq>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='IsComplete' /><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Approved' /><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq>
            </Or>
        </Or>
</And>
</Where>
```

The Query runs but it seems to ignore the last part of the statement as it is pulling back things where the `Relationship = N/A`.

Comment: I think your last And should goes into the first And after the last Or

Comment: Using a tool to formulate queries like these would eliminate common errors.

Comment: no tools that I've tried can generate such a complicated query @uberz91. Suggestions?

Comment: @Colbs i find U2U query builder pretty useful for these cases. I'm sure it will be able to handle this.

Comment: You could also use https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/ to test your queries or use U2U Query Builder.

Comment: Are you checking null values for Relationship or value 'N/A' ?

Answer (score 2):

According to your condition following should be the CAML Query.

**Condition**

```
(Country == US) && (Status BeginsWith A || Status BeginsWith B || Status BeginsWith C || Status BeginsWith D || Status BeginsWith E || Status BeginsWith F) && (Relationship != NA || IsComplete == Yes || IsApproved == Yes)
```

**CAML Query**

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <And>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Country'/><Value Type='Text'>US</Value></Eq>
            <Or>
                <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>A</Value></BeginsWith>
                <OR>
                    <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>B</Value></BeginsWith>
                    <OR>
                        <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>C</Value></BeginsWith>
                        <OR>
                            <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>D</Value></BeginsWith>
                            <Or>
                                <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>E</Value></BeginsWith>
                                <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>F</Value></BeginsWith>
                            </Or>
                        </Or>
                    </Or>
                </Or>
            </Or>
        </And>
        <Or>
            <Neq><FieldRef Name='Relationship'/><Value Type='Text'>N/A</Value></Neq>
            <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='IsComplete'/><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='IsApproved'/><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq>
            </Or>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You must first understand how it works and how to write.Then you can do it on your own.

**How To Write Dynamic CAML :**

While writing CAML query, you must understand the architecture how it works.

It is pretty simple. You just have to do logical `AND`/`OR` operators.

Any operator must have 2 conditions to combine and test.

**SCENARIO 1 :** This is 1 Operator use with 2 conditions

```
 <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
 </Or>
```

**SCENARIO 2 :** This is 2 Operators use with 2 conditions 
From scenario 1 we got operator now along with that we will add another  operator.

```
<And>
    <Or>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(3) TestStatus3</Value></Eq>
       <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(2) TestStatus2</Value></Eq>              
    </Or>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Text'>(1) TestStatus1</Value></Eq>                  
</And>
```

Here if you notice, `<OR>` is having two conditions inside it. and that makes 1 condition for outer `<And>`, so we added another condition block parallel to `<OR>` operator. Hence 2 conditions are available for `<AND>`.

Likewise you can build ***n*** number of nested conditions.

PS: If you have only 1 condition, it will not require any operator.